# Movement of Electricity in a Simple Circuit: A Few Simple Questions and a Diagram

Tags: movement

[image]

The diagram above is of two batteries a light bulb and some cables. A book that I am reading shows that electricity would not flow through the blue cable, it would flow through the red cable. This left me with the following questions:

1. Is this even true? why wouldn't some of the electrons from the battery on the right still try to flow to the battery on the left? (this kind of relates to question 3).
2. Also suppose that the cable extending from the negative terminal (the anode) of the battery on the left was many times longer than the length of the cable extending from anode of the battery on the right, in such a case would electricity be transferred from the anode of the battery on the right to the positive terminal (cathode) of the battery on the left? In other words do the electrons take the path of least resistance?
3. Pardon the analogy that follows; would a sort of traffic jam be created where the blue and the red cable connect? I mean once the electron from one battery started flowing to the cathode, would they impede other electrons from joining the flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider electricity as having two co-existing components (this is not strictly correct but it's good for beginners).  The first component is "voltage".  Voltage is an electric field which propagates at a significant fraction of the speed of light through a conductor (I think roughly 200 million meters per second).  When you first connect the red wire to the + on the battery, the field propagates very quickly throughout the red wire, and even down the blue wire.

The second component is "current".  Current is the actual motion of the electrons, and current is "caused" by the voltage "pushing" electrons.  Compared to the electric field that is the voltage, current moves at a glacial pace of *1 meter per hour*.  One of the requirements for current is that the voltage can travel in a closed loop from one side of the voltage source to the other.

That is why

1. Yes, this is true.  No electrons from the battery on the right move because there is no closed loop for them to return to the battery.  The voltage field propagates to the battery on the right, but it cannot cause electrons to move without a closed loop.
2. Electrons take the path of least resistance, but for the blue wire, *the resistance of the path is infinite*, because it is not a closed loop, therefore no current flows.
3. There is no traffic jam because no current flows down the right wire.  However, if you are using the voltage of the signal to transfer information, you may see distortion that is caused by the field propagating down the blue wire and then slamming into the infinite resistance. (this is why The Photon prefaced with the comment about "steady-state analysis")

Comment: I dislike the statement "Electrons take the path of least resistance" because beginners seem inclined to read it as "electrons take _only_ the path of least resistance".  This is incorrect, as electrons (or really current) will take all possible paths, in inverse proprotion to the path's resistances - a low resistance path will carry a higher current than a high resistance path, but the high resistance path will still carry _some_ current.

Comment: Agreed, I don't much like the phrase either.  I had a professor who used the auditorium analogy.  Imagine a set of double-doors, and another single door, leading into an auditorium.  People choose the path of least resistance, but at some point the double-doors are "full", and that path no longer "appears" to have the lowest resistance, so people start choosing the single-door.  The open circuit would be like another door which was closed, which will never have the lowest resistance even when the other doors are full.  An imperfect analogy, to be sure, but you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

This question is about steady-state dc analysis, and my answer applies to the steady state condition.

> Is this even true? why wouldn't some of the electrons from the battery on the right still try to flow to the battery on the left? (this kind of relates to question 3).

The battery on the right is not part of a complete circuit. Therefore no current will flow through it. To form a complete circuit there must be a path for current to flow from the + terminal back to the - terminal.

> Also suppose that the cable extending from the negative terminal (the anode) of the battery on the left was many times longer than the length of the cable extending from anode of the battery on the right, in such a case would electricity be transferred from the anode of the battery on the right to the positive terminal (cathode) of the battery on the left? In other words do the electrons take the path of least resistance?

The battery on the right is still not part of a complete circuit, so no current will flow through it.

> Pardon the analogy that follows; would a sort of traffic jam be created where the blue and the red cable connect? I mean once the electron from one battery started flowing to the cathode, would they impede other electrons from joining the flow?

Without a complete circuit through the battery on the right, it doesn't matter.

Even if both batteries were connected in parallel, the connection of two wires would not cause a traffic jam and impede the flow of current.

However, the light bulb acts as a resistor. As such, if you apply a given voltage (12 V, say), it will only draw current according to its resistance. If the voltage is applied by two batteries in parallel, part of that current will come from one battery and part from another, so that Ohm's law is satisfied for the resistor (light bulb). In this way, you might consider the light bulb to be causing a kind of traffic jam, in that it *resists* the flow of current.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up:  If the voltage is applied by two batteries in parallel, part of that current will come from one battery and part from another, so that Ohm's law is satisfied for the resistor (light bulb).

Answer (score 4):

This kind of question is difficult to answer because you are including too many myths in your question that need to be dispelled before you are in a position to understand a real answer.  In other words, you need a basic introduction to electricity, which is too much material to teach in a answer on this Q&A site.  I'll therefore just mention a few things:

Yes, the book is correct.  Current must flow in a loop.  The battery at right is not part of any loop.

Talking about "electricity" flowing is meaningless and you will continue to be confused until you clear up the basic conceptual problem behind this wrong use of terms.  There is EMF (usually measured in volts and often referred to as "voltage") and there is "current".  There is no such physical quantity as "electricity".

Go learn *voltage* and *current*.  Until then, trying to talk to you will be too cumbersome and probably wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the first part. I am reading Code by Charles Petzold, if it requires a lot more electricity in depth i will pick up a textbook.